# CAML Query throwing error

Tags: caml

Pretty new to CAML queries, but trying to query a list based on Status = Completed and a date range.

It is throwing the following error "Unexpected Error: One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.
Microsoft.SharePoint"

Status and Created are both system columns, so pretty sure I have the Field Names correct
I have tested the query without the Date Range and it runs as expected, so I think my problem is somewhere in between  and . From what I have read, Created expects time to follow date. Query is below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<Where>   
<And>                               
   <And>    
      <Eq><FieldRef Name="Status" />Value Type="Choice">Completed</Value></Eq> 
   </And>          
      <Geq>         
         <FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE"    
Type="DateTime">2013-07-02T00:00:01Z</Value>
  </Geq>
       <Leq>              
          <FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" 
Type="DateTime">2013-07-02T23:59:59Z</Value>
       </Leq>
</And> 
</Where>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some basic syntax errors in your query above, so they may be causing the issue.  See if this helps.

- You were missing a left angle-bracket in the first  tag.
- You had too many  tags and they were out of sequence.
- I changed the Type attribute of the first  tag to Text.

  ```
  <Where>   
  <And>    
      <Eq><FieldRef Name="Status" /><Value Type="Text">Completed</Value></Eq> 
      <And>          
          <Geq>         
              <FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2013-07-02T00:00:01Z</Value>
          </Geq>
          <Leq>              
              <FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2013-07-02T23:59:59Z</Value>
          </Leq>
      </And>
  </And> 
  </Where>
  ```